# web2py - load part of data

Tags: web2py

i have table called "type" which contains data "family,individual" i want in some pages load individual only into type drop-down and in another pages load both

How can i do that??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
You can set the default in the model:

```
db.yourtable.yourfield.requires=IS_IN_SET(('family','individual'))
```

In any action you can do

```
db.yourtable.yourfield.requires=IS_IN_SET(('family'))
```